# Декоратор вместо контейнера

Tags: reactjs, redux

Подключил к react проекту декораторы. В таком виде код работает:

```
// setTitle.js decorator
/**
  title is a string that will be set as a document title
  WrappedComponent is what our decorator will receive when
  put directly above a component class as seen in the example above
*/
import React from "react";


export const setTitle = getTitle => (WrappedComponent) => {

    return class extends React.Component {

        updateTitle = (props) => {
            // Check if the callback has returned something,
            // and if so - update the title
            const title = getTitle(props)
            if(title) {
                document.title = title
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.updateTitle(this.props)
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
            this.updateTitle(props)
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }
}

// Component which is using decorator
@setTitle(()=>'Kamasutra community')
class Community extends React.Component
{
    render () {
        return <div>
            <CommunityListContainerIO />
            {/* UpdateCommunity /> */}
        </div>
    }
}

export default Community;
```

Теперь хочу чтобы этот декоратор работал с redux, нагружаю декоратор коннектором из react-redux модуля

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

/** SetTitle redux wrapper */
let mapStateToProps = (state) =>
{
    return {
        /** Page title */
        title: state.title
    }
}

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
{
    return {
        /** Follow member with given id */
        setTitle: (title) => { dispatch( SetTitleAC(title) ) }
    }
}

/** SetTitle decorator */
export const setTitle = (getTitle) => (WrappedComponent) => {

    return class extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            document.title = props.title
        }

        updateTitle = (props) => {
            // Check if the callback has returned something,
            // and if so - update the title
            const title = getTitle(props)
            if(title) {
                //props.setTitle(title)
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.updateTitle(this.props)
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
            this.updateTitle(props)
        }

        render() {
            //return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
            return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WrappedComponent)
        }
    }
}


/** SetTitle reducer */
const SET_TITLE = 'SET_TITLE'

let initialState =
    {
        title:'kamasutra'
    }

const titleReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        /** Start following user with given userId*/
        case SET_TITLE: {
            return { ...state, title:state.title }
        }

        default: return state
    }
}
export default titleReducer

export const SetTitleAC = title => { return { type:SET_TITLE, title } }
```

И ... реакт ругается на использование WrappedComponent в методе connect ...

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {$$typeof, type, compare, WrappedComponent}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал!

```
/**
  title is a string that will be set as a document title
  WrappedComponent is what our decorator will receive when
  put directly above a component class as seen in the example above
*/
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

/** SetTitle redux wrapper */
let mapStateToProps = (state) =>
{
    return {

        /** Page title */
        title: state.document.title
    }
}

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
{
    return {
        /** Follow member with given id */
        setTitle: (title) => { dispatch( SetTitleAC(title) ) }
    }
}

/** SetTitle decorator */
export const setTitle = (getTitle) => (WrappedComponent) => {

    class SetTitleDecorator extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            document.title = props.title
        }

        updateTitle = (props) => {
            const title = getTitle(props)
            if(title) {
                document.title = title
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.updateTitle(this.props)
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
            this.updateTitle(props)
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }

    const SetTitleDecoratorConnector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SetTitleDecorator)
    return SetTitleDecoratorConnector

}
```